# using a query in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

My proplem : I couldn't displaying data i want right after i conduct a query from angularjs file and Controller file.
This is my Angularjs file:

```
$scope.confirmCapnhat=function(p_id,dn_ngayLap){
            if($scope.p_id!="" && $scope.dn_ngayLap!="")
            {
                 var thang=dn_ngayLap.getMonth();
                var Nam=dn_ngayLap.getFullYear();
                if(thang>9)
                        var NamThang=Nam+"-"+thang; 
                else
                        var NamThang=Nam+"-0"+thang;

                $http.get(API+'diennuoc/'+p_id+'/'+NamThang+'/capnhat').then(successCallback,errorCallback);
                function successCallback(response){
                    // $scope.name = "John Doe";
                    console.log(response);
                    $scope.diennuoc=response.data;
                };
                function errorCallback(response){
                    $scope.sodauDien=0;
                    $scope.sodauNuoc=0;
                };  
            }
            else
            alert('Chưa chọn phòng hoặc ngày lập!');

        }
```

And In my routes file (web.php), i define as:  `Route::get('diennuoc/{p_id}/{dn_ngayLap}/capnhat','DienNuocController@capnhat');`
The below is my Controller file:

```
 public function capnhat($p_id,$dn_ngayLap)
    {

            $sql="select * from diennuoc where p_id='".$p_id."' and dn_ngayLap='".$dn_ngayLap."'";
            $diennuoc=DB::select($sql);
        return $diennuoc;
    }
```

When i run it in Blade.php source,i click a button in the middle of source (ng-click="confirmCapnhat(p_id,dn_ngayLap)"). it doesn't display data below.
My Blade.php :

```
<div class="box box-default" ng-controller="DienNuocController">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Thêm điện nước</h3>  
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
          <form class="form-horizontal" name="frmdiennuoc" method="POST" action="{{route('diennuoc.store')}}">
             {{csrf_field()}}
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPassword3"  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ngày lập:</label>

                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                 <div class="input-group date">
                      <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                         <input type="month" class="form-control" name="dn_ngayLap" value="{{old('dn_ngayLap')}}" ng-model="dn_ngayLap" />
                        </div> 
                  </div>
                </div>
                <% dn_ngayLap %>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phòng:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="p_id" id="p_id" ng-model="p_id">
                     @foreach($dsphong as $phong)
                        <option value="{{$phong->p_id}}">{{$phong->p_ten}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" ng-hide="myVar">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cập nhật tháng trước" ng-click="confirmCapnhat(p_id,dn_ngayLap)" >
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eyedropper"></i></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bolt"></i>Điện</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Chỉ số đầu:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="dn_sodauDien" class="form-control" id="dn_sodauDien" value="<% diennuoc.dn_socuoiDien %>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="add-on icon-tint"></i>Chỉ số cuối:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="dn_socuoiDien" class="form-control" id="dn_socuoiDien">
                  </div>
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eyedropper"></i></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-flask"></i>Nước</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Chỉ số đầu:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="dn_sodauNuoc" class="form-control" id="dn_sodauNuoc" value="<% diennuoc.dn_socuoiNuoc %>" >
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="add-on icon-tint"></i>Chỉ số cuối:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="dn_socuoiNuoc" class="form-control" id="dn_socuoiNuoc" value="{{old('dn_socuoiNuoc')}}" 
                  >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.form-group -->
            <!-- /.col -->
         <!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info">
                Thêm
              </button>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </form>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
```

How could i get if each times i get as picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF6dq.png)

Comment: your data is populated in a scoped variable within a controller. So you should be pulling it out with `ng-model="diennuoc.dn_socuoiDien"` in your input filed. Don't render anything with `<% ... %>` syntax, angularjs can do that for you. It's a bad practice to mix PHP and angularjs

Comment: ok!. i try it with ng-model="diennuoc.dn_socuoiDien" but it's still not displaying data. but in my console.log(response) is : {data: Array(1), status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", …}. i don't understand?

Comment: Data in console log is alright but it couldn't display

Comment: check your `response.data`, it seems like you are returning an array, so using `diennuoc.dn_socuoiDien` is impossible. Maybe you wanted `diennuoc[0].dn_socuoiDien` (with index 0 as the first element of an array)

Comment: oh! thank you so much... i get it. Your solution is great. This issue that i haven't solved it many times :).